# Usage - ngForm with ng-content

Tags: angular

I would like to create component like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

But if I check the validation of this form, it's always true (`{{ form.valid }}`).

From the parent component it looks like:

```
<app-form-component>
    <input [(ngModel)]="variable" required minlength="3">
</app-form-component>
```

I think that I should provide some thinks in FormComponent, but I don't know what. I tried to add:

```
providers: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useClass: NgForm }],
```

but it doesn't work.

I expect to find way to correct validation my form.

Comment: Well, it seems like you don't have any actual `FormControls` in your form. Why do you expect the form to be invalid? Or do you actually want to bind your input to a form control instead of binding it via `ngModel`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is just recreating the `ReactiveFormsModule`. Stop using template driven forms, use reactive forms, you'll get what you're asking for.

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="username" type="text">
</form>
```

```js
form = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

Comment: I asked about sth totaly difrent.........

Comment: What you're trying to implement with your `FormComponent` is actually a reactive form. That's why I made this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that content is intialized before the view (because it is actually the part of parent's template), and therefore controls don't find the form itself in their injector tree.

You could do something tricky like put ngIf in the parent's template that is `false` initially, and  switches to true in setTimeout, or pass `<ng-template>` instead of actual template to app-form-component and render it when the view is initialized. But I would better try to put both the form and its content into one component